# Surround tags in vim

Tags: vim, surround

I often want to surround a div tag with another div tag.
https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround is a real help there.

```
|<div>
  ...
</div>
```

if the cursor is at | and I type`ysat<div>` I get

```
<div><div>
  ...
</div><div>
```

instead I want

```
<div>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

how can I force the div to be on a new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help at` says:

> When used in Visual mode it is made characterwise.

The low-level mechanism used by Surround for its `ys` custom operator consumes the given motion as a visual selection, the type of which is then used by the plugin to decide what to do. In this case, Surround gets a characterwise motion which makes it operate in a characterwise fashion.

In order to achieve your goal, you will need to force a *linewise* motion by adding a `V` between the operator (`ys`) and the motion (`at`):

```
ysVat<div><CR>
  ^
```

See `:help forced-motion`:

```
                            *o_V*
V       When used after an operator, before the motion command: Force
        the operator to work linewise, also when the motion is
        characterwise.
```